# Can existence be felt in itinere? Mistaken inference

Tags: probability

I'm dwelling on a very simple question.

I have a closed box with ***n*** black balls. A malicious friend of mine COULD had exchanged a black ball for a white ball. I want to know wheather this happened but I can check the balls only extracting them one by one from the box.
While I'm searching for the white ball and the number of observed (black) balls grows does the probability of finding the white one diminish?

Does speaking of changing probability even make sense? If I could see all the ball at once, I wouldn't have felt any odds against me in the process. So seems obvious that the process of checking can't tell me anything (about the presence of the white ball) unless completed. Is this true?

Suppose the white ball is in there and I find it on the ***n-th*** observation. Now, in hindsight, I know that what happened was the most unlikely, because the expected checks were $\mathbf{\frac{n+1}{2}}$.

Ultimately, while I'm searching for the white ball and aproaching the last balls, this sentence would be correct:

```
(1) << If the white ball is in here, it would be very unlikely! >>
```

But the counter-intuitive thing is that the presence of the white ball can't be affected by this later-unravelled (un)likelihood.
So, in the aforementioned situation to think this would be incorrect:

```
(2) << It's very unlikely for the white ball to be in here! >>
```

With this the wrong(?) tranferring of the likelihood from the second event (expected observation to spot the white ball) to the first (presence of the white ball):

```
(2') << If the white ball is in here, I would have already seen it.  
        I haven't seen it yet, then it shouldn't be in here. >>
```

Funny thing, I hadn't foreseen to answered myself... Have I?
It remainds me of [Raven paradox](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments).

PS: I've deliberately not introduced the probability of my friend to excange the balls because I thought it irrelevant for he sake of the question. Anyway if necessary it should be view as $\mathbf{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe part of your question (but not all of it) involves a maximum likelihood estimate:
https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metodo_della_massima_verosimiglianza

For the moment let's defer the other part of your question involving the probability of sequences. First let's consider the maximum likelihood estimate, which tells you whether it is likely that your friend switched the ball.

### Maximum Likelihood

Let unknown parameter X represent whether your friend switched a black ball for a white ball, where x=0 means that no switch was made, and x=1 means the switch was made.

You observe the balls you pull from the bag and use these observations to calculate two conditional probabilities:

$P(what-you-observed | x=0)$

$P(what-you-observed | x=1)$

If $P(what-you-observed|x=0) > P(what-you-observed|x=1)$ then you conclude it is more likely the switch was *not* made, and vice versa if the inequality is reversed.

Consider your example where the $n^{th}$ ball you pull from the bag is white. Obviously if you pull the ball from the bag you know x=1. Similarly if you pull $n$ black balls from the bag you know $x=0$.

Now assume you have pulled $n-1$ balls from the bag and they are all black. How improbable is this sequence of $n-1$ black balls?

Let the observed event be "When I pull $n-1$ balls they will all be black". The first conditional probability is trivial because there are more than $n-1$ balls and they are all black:

$P(n-1-black-balls | x=0) = 1$

The second conditional probability is not much harder:

$P(n-1-black-balls| x=1) = (\frac{n-1}{n}) (\frac{n-2}{n-1}) ... (\frac{1}{2})$

For very large $n$ the second conditional probability will be very small, so the maximum likelihood is that $x=0$, i.e. no switch was made. This matches your intuition in your statements (2) and (2') that as you pull more balls from the bag and don't see a white ball, the chance that there actually is a white ball diminishes.

In summary, you're correct that the *presence* of the white ball can't be affected by "the later-unravelled (un)likelihood", but the *likelihood of the presence* of the white ball is so affected.

### Likelihood of a particular sequence of balls

In the example above where $n-1$ black balls are pulled from the bag, the conditional probability is very small. This conditional probability is what you address in your statement (1):
$P(what-you-observed | x=1) = (\frac{n-1}{n}) (\frac{n-2}{n-1}) ... (\frac{1}{2})$

In other words, the conditional probability of this sequence of balls, given that the switch was made, is very small.

---

Note that this does not introduce the probability of your friend exchanging the balls, as you stated.

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track! But I have some doubts on the order relation between $P(k-black-balls|x=0)$ and $P(k-black-balls|x=1)$ the first will in any case be $1$ and the second always less than $1$. Then I'll conclude it is always more likely the switch was *not* made since the beginning of observations... And I can't weight that $1$ otherwise I'll be consciously influence the evaluation like I knew the odds. This seems flawed.  
Even if we only focus on variation, $P(k-black-balls|x=1)$ will be strictly decreasing, so will the *likelihood of the presence* form the start?

Comment: @DomenicoModica I think you're concerned that $P(k−black−balls|x=0) > P(k−black−balls|x=1)$ for any k black balls you pull out of the bag. Don’t forget the reverse inequality is possible, even though $P(k−black−balls|x=0) <= P(k−black−balls|x=1)$ only when you pull a white ball. This of course means you have certainty that x=1, and it's disappointing that you have no ‘hint’ that the probability was shifting from ‘more likely that x=0’ to ‘more likely that x=1’. But the important point is that as you pull balls from the bag $P(k−black−balls|x=1)$ is not necessarily strictly decreasing.

Comment: @DomenicoModica Perhaps it is worth noting that $P(k−black−balls|x=0) > P(k−black−balls|x=1)$ does *not* mean it is *certain* that x=0, only that x=0 is more likely than x=1 (which is still possible if there are balls remaining in the bag).

Also, I’m not sure what you mean by “I can't weight that 1 otherwise I'll be consciously influence the evaluation like I knew the odds”. What evaluation exactly would you like to make?

Comment: Yes, I meant strictly decreasing during the non-finding of the white ball, after all that's what I see when I ask myself whether  x=1. Also never mind that weight idea, was a rush attempt to give more meaning at that inequality, I couldn't wrap my head around the fact probability always diminish in search process.

Comment: Anyway I've found Bayes' theorem is fully suitable to the problem. And it gives the same answer, provided that the probabilty of the switch is introduced, not a big deal: it can be any $p, 0<p<1$ the behavior is the same, it's always decreasing from the beginning (if white ball doesn't show up). I've worked out it's halved at $k - black -ball$ where $k\geq{{\frac{n}{2-p}}}$